# Yellow leaves on rhododendron

Tags: rhododendrons

[image: rhododendron]
2017, 1st june
Soon after planting my rhododendron, leaves are turning yellow with black/brownish patches. Is it dying? Can I do anything about it?

Edit (2017, 12th july):
I didnt do much. Looks much  better now. Guess wait and see was the right thing to do

[image: Rhododendron updated]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest keeping an eye on the plant.  If the overall health of the plant looks good, I would not worry about it.  It seems like the rest of the plant is healthy.  Plants do go through some shock after transplanting.